# Indent paragraphs in a beamer block

Tags: beamer, indentation

I want every new paragraph *except the first one* in a \begin{block} to be indented. This is the standard in other document classes. I already put `\setlength\parindent{1cm}` in my preamble, but this indents the first paragraph. It's a small thing, but I'd like to be consistent with the other document classes. I also have a problem with my Lemma and Theorem headers being indented along with the text, which is really bad. How do I do this in a beamer?

Comment: Use `\noindent` in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Fran I don't want to type that at every paragraph. There has to be a way to set it globally.

Comment: I suppose that redefine the environment, but I prefer the simple approach. After all,  a presentation should not have many paragraphs.

Comment: @Fran I'm making a poster with beamerposter, it has a lot of paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

Here would be my approach using `beamer`'s "templating" capabilities and LaTeX's mechanism for disabling indentation after headings:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} % just to have some style around the content
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{block}{Test}
Test

Test
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Test}
Test

Test
\end{block}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the extra space without `\ignorespaces` is a spurious space in your code:-) the space after `{Test}` try putting `%` at end of that line.

Comment: better as \makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatletter
 though (then still works if there is a space or even a blank line before \lipsum)

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, you've made me realize the errors of my ways yet again. :-)